# How to get Doxygen to parse Function pointer typedefs containing __cdecl?

Tags: function-pointers, typedef, doxygen

When using MS C or GNU C where you need to use **__cdecl**, function pointer prototypes look like:

- typedef int (**__cdecl** *funcname_ptr)(void* arg1, const char* arg2);
- typedef int(**__attribute__((cdecl))** *funcname_ptr)(void* arg1, const char* arg2);

It seems that the text prior to *funcname_ptr causes doxygen's parser to fail.

If you have run into this issue, have you found a workaround?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I haven't encountered this problem, but one workaround may be to predefine __cdecl as a  macro that evaluates to nothing in the doxygen configuration file using the [PREDEFINED](http://www.doxygen.nl/manual/config.html#cfg_predefined) option.

Comment: Thanks for the suggestion. Unfortunately, it doesn't change the output of Doxygen.

Comment: It turns out you were correct, but I didn't quite get my attempt correct.  I misunderstood the Doxygen documentation and mistakenly thought that I only needed to set EXPAND_ONLY_PREDEF to YES. It turns out you must also set MACRO_EXPANSION to YES. So, the complete solution is to: `1) Set MACRO_EXPANSION = YES, 2) Set EXPAND_ONLY_PREDEF = YES, 3) Set PREDEFINED = __cdecl= __attribute__((cdecl))= AnythingElseYouWantToDisappear=`